# PromQL increase function is not producing what I expect

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics, promql, open-telemetry

I want to create a query that generates the amount of network traffic out(bytes) over the last 24 hours.

The metrics are being collected and exported with the help of open-telemetry, to Mimir, which is used as datasource by Grafana.

What I thought would work was

```
sum(increase(system_network_io{service_name="foo", environment="bar", direction="transmit"}[24h]))
```

But this ends up generating a value close to 610 Terrabytes of network traffic which is unreasonably high.

But if I try to get the difference between the current value and the 24h offset value I get something close to 2,7 GB of network traffic which is pretty reasonable

```
sum(system_network_io{service_name="foo", environment="bar", direction="transmit"}) - sum(system_network_io{service_name="foo", environment="bar", direction="transmit"} offset 24h)
```

Here is an image of what the time series looks like when querying, while showing the last 7 days. The reason I want to use increase function is because, as I've understood it, it can workaround resets. And if we look at the image it looks like there has been some kind of reset, but not set to 0. But in my opinion this shouldn't affect the first query as it is well outside the time range of 24 hours.

```
system_network_io{service_name="foo", environment="bar", direction="transmit"}
```

[time_series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7u23.png)
Appreciate any help

Comment: Are you sure you are seeing mentioned 610TB as "raw" data, and not as, for example, total of all values due to set aggregation method in panel?

Comment: I mean is that intended by the increase function? If I just use the increase() function, without sum() it gives me 2 graphs, but their sum adds up to the 610TB.

Comment: No, this is not normal. And `increase` doesn't usually do this. You either interpret output wrong, or you have some significant issues with your data (within the last day). Also, counter that resets not to a zero is not OK, and will result in troubles in `increase` (and similar functions that process resets), but not as much trouble as you see IMO.

Comment: I have 2 different applications sending metrics, and I noticed that one of the applications get the same result from using the 2 different ways I proposed to calculate the network traffic over 24h, but the other gives a huge difference

Comment: I think I know what might be causing the problem, but not why. The application where this high value is produced is load balanced between 2 instances.

Comment: You shouldn't scrape system metrics through load balancer. Counters will jump around, and every decrease in value will be interpreted as a reset. Scrape backend services individually instead.

Comment: The metrics are being scraped directly from the instances and not through the load balancer. On each instance there is an identical open-telemetry collector running, which exports the data to the monitoring backend.